# CloudFront issue with path pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have DevOps intuition about how CDN works and what are its advantages. Before asking this question, I have searched about it in similar stackoverflow questions but I feel a little confused now.

**Problem Description**

Imagine I have two different prefixes in the same bucket:

1. `/<bucket-name>/maintenance`
2. `/<bucket-name>/assets`

The problem is that whenever I enter the following URL with the `<distribution-domain-name>/maintenance/*` format, it doesn't return the content and raise an `Access Denied` error.

**What I want to achieve**:

Create two different routes, on `<distribution-domain-name>/maintenance/*` (for maintenance contents) and another one one `<distribution-domain-name>/*`. If the URL starts with `<distribution-domain-name>/maintenance/*` whatever is replaced to `*` should be existed on the  `/<bucket-name>/maintenance` instance.

**What I have done**

I have create two origins:

- Modify origin path (the prefix of the bucket)

[image: origin path]

- Add two different behaviors, one for maintenance and another for default queries.

[image: path pattern]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**‌Introduction**

Before diving into the solution, I would like to mention, as stated in the first sentence of my question, that CloudFront is not functioning as expected, which is quite peculiar.
So I think it is worth to mention the solution in details.

**Solution**

To address the issue, please follow these steps in sequence:

1. Create two origins for the problem.
2. Set the origin path to the S3 bucket **without the last prefix**. (In my case, the first origin path should be `/services` instead of `/service/maintenance`)

   **P.S**: This is so weird. If you have added path pattern like `maintenance/*` in the CloudFront behavior and origin of S3 equals to `/services/maintenance`, it is required to add new prefix (directory) in S3 bucket! For this purpose instead of adding a new prefix, I have modified the origin path to `/services`.
3. [Optional] If the directory mentioned in the `path pattern` does not exist, take appropriate action.